# JavaScript createElement help

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
function JS_Utils_BuildModal ()
        {

            var objModal = document.createElement("div");

            objModal.setAttribute('id', 'Modal');

            document.body.appendChild(objModal);

        }
```

What I want to do is add to it and create a series of DIVS and P's with some content so that when I run the function I get the following:

```
<div id="Modal">
<div class="Content">
<p>Sending Data</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Is your question how to get the element nesting?

Answer (score 1):

Really it's just a matter of duplicating the createElement and appendChild parts of your code, and then setting the relevant properties on the other objects:

```
function JS_Utils_BuildModal () 
{ 
    var objModal   = document.createElement("div"); 
    var objContent = document.createElement("div");
    var objP       = document.createElement("p");
    objModal.setAttribute('id', 'Modal');
    objContent.className = 'Content';
    objP.innerText = "Sending Data";
    objModal.appendChild(objContent);
    objContent.appendChild(objP); 
    document.body.appendChild(objModal); 
}
```

Alternatively, you could do the whole thing/part of it with the `innerHTML` property, like so:

```
function JS_Utils_BuildModal () 
{ 
    var objModal   = document.createElement("div");
    objModal.setAttribute('id', 'Modal');
    objModal.innerHTML = '<div class="Content"><p>Sending Data</p></div>';
    document.body.appendChild(objModal); 
}
```

Using `innerHTML` is generally slower than directly manipulating the DOM, because it invokes the HTML parser.  It's still fast enough in most cases, though.

Comment: Cool thanks. What if I want to do this:

objP.innerText = "Sending Data (<a href='javascript:S_Utils_HideModal();'>cancel</a>)";

Also I'm wanting to show this Modal box when a user submits a form, what would I add to the HideModal function to stop the page if it's in the middle of a postback? Thanks

Comment: @Cameron: If you're adding HTML to the `<p>`, you can use the `innerHTML` property instead of `innerText`, or you can create the `<a>` element with `createElement` again and append it after setting the `innerText` property.

Answer (score 0):

```
function JS_Utils_BuildModal()
{
    // Create parent div
    var objModal = document.createElement("div");
    objModal.setAttribute('id', 'Modal');
    document.body.appendChild(objModal);

    // Create modal div
    var objContent = document.createElement("div");
    objContent.setAttribute("id", "Content");
    objModal.appendChild(objContent);

    // Create sending data paragraph
    var objData = document.createElement("p");
    objContent.appendChild(objData);
}
```

The appendChild() method will work on any DOM element. document.body is a DOM element for the document's body.

Edit: Looks like Andy E already answered the question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

about innerhtml, it is actually faster than dom:
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/innerhtml.html